# Split String with more Symbols

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I need help. I tried to split a String, but I did not find the perfect way.

Example:

```
string data = "Car1@4$doors&1$engine&100$horsepower&2$color"
```

I want to split this string. The result is also a string and should look like `4 doors, 1 engine, 100 horsepower, 2 color`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems are you having with your implementation?

Comment: *I tried* — what did you try?

Comment: How about you replace all characters that aren't in [a-Z] or [0-9] with a white space? Seems pretty simple to me... You have two classes of characters, alphanumeric ones and non-alphanumeric ones, all you're trying to do is replace non alphanumeric ones with white spaces...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Except he's not.  Look at the results, there's more than just whitespace there.  In any event, it's likely preferable to actually parse the data, so that you can then display it however you want.  Odds are he wants to actually use the information at some point, not just display it again.

Comment: I started to split the data with this lines:

string[] TruckName = truckdata.Split('@');
string[] TruckTypes = TruckName[1].Split('&');

so, now im not sure how to merg the data back to a string

Comment: @user2996927 Include that information in the question.  You're further along than half of the answers at this point.

Comment: @Servy yeah that's true, replacing only with whitespaces would not be sufficient. The whole two classes of characters part still holds though and should be a starting point because I see a bunch of terrible answers that try to replace each specific special character when that is obviously not a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = string.Join(", ", data.Substring(data.IndexOf("@") + 1).Replace("$", " ").Split('&'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ugliest line I could come up with to answer your question.
Enjoy!

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", "Car1@4$doors&1$engine&100$horsepower&2$color".Split('@').Select(s => s.Replace("&", ", ").Replace('$', ' '))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation, of course you can remove the matching `{0}`

```
string data = "Car1@4$doors&1$engine&100$horsepower&2$color";
string[] dataArray = data.Split('@');
string carProperties = dataArray[1].Replace("$", " ").Replace('&', ',');
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dataArray[0], carProperties);
```